custom fixed width of column not working on reload/ revisit the tab
i've provided custom fixed width to some columns in my table but the it's not working on revisit the tab and sometimes on reload.
[ {
headerName: 'Funnel stage',
field: 'event_type',
sortable: false,
filter: true,
suppressMenu: true,
resizable: false,
cellRenderer: ({ data }: ICellRendererParams) => (
<EventTypeDropdown
data={eventConfigData!}
currentEvent={data}
isStatusIgnored={data.status === EventStatus.Blocked}
/>
),
width: 268, //fixed
headerClass: 'table-column-header-cell',
},
]
i tried 'sizeColumnsToFit()' but, it didn't work .
